# How to find Duplicate values in Dict and print keys with those values

Tags: python, dictionary, key, duplicates

I wanted to know how I can find duplicate values in a dictionary and the return the keys that contain those values.

So here is an example:

```
d = {'happy':['sun', 'moon', 'chocolate'], 'sad':['fail', 'test', 'bills'], 'random': ['baloon', 'france', 'sun'] }
```

As you can see the key's **happy** and **random** have the same/duplicate value in them, which is **'sun'**, so the output I was looking for is:

```
random, happy
```

I cant really understand how I can find duplicate values like that.

If I had a particular value such as 'Chocolate', then I could simply do a for loop using d.keys() ...

Comment: What do you want the output to be if two different pairs of keys share different words (for example if in your example `sad` also contained `moon`)?

Comment: Yes so even if 2 or more than 2, different keys shared atleast 1 common value. Then those 2 (or more) keys should be printed

Comment: of course the common values can be more than 1.. but at least 1. Then the function should print those keys, that share common values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

super quick and dirty

```
d = {'happy':['sun', 'moon', 'chocolate'], 'sad':['fail', 'test', 'bills'], 'random': ['baloon', 'france', 'sun'] }
specific_word = 'bear' #uncomment to search for specific word

for key_a in d: #loop through the keys of d
   for key_b in d: #loop a second time through the keys of d
       if key_a == key_b: #if the keys are the same, skip it
           break
       for item in d[key_a]: #loop through items in d[key_a]
           if (item in d[key_b]): #check if the item is in d[key_b]
           #if you want to search ONLY for specific_word then this above if statement changes to this:
           #if (item in d[key_b]) and item == specific_word:
               print key_a,key_b #if u made it this far, print the keys
               break # stop printing other stuff, in case of multiple matches
```

in definition form: ( You should pretty much always try to do it like this)

```
def duplicate_dictionary_check(d,specific_word=''):
    for key_a in d:
       for key_b in d
           if key_a == key_b:
               break
           for item in d[key_a]:
               if (item in d[key_b]):
                   if specific_word:
                        if specific_word == item:
                            print key_a,key_b,"found specific word:", specific_word
                   print key_a,key_b,"found match:",item
```

then you can play around with this like

```
 d = {'happy':['sun', 'moon', 'chocolate'], 'sad':['fail', 'test', 'bills'], 'random': ['baloon', 'france', 'sun'] }
 duplicate_dictionary_check(d)
 # or
 duplicate_dictionary_check(d,'sun')
```

Comment: Amazing ! great explanation in your answers !

Comment: okay one more followup question to this: What if you you were given a value say 'Bear' and you were asked to see if 'bear' exists as a duplicate in the dictionary.. how would that work?

Comment: Also what if there are more than 2 keys with common values.

Comment: You would probably want to form the entire thing into an actual defintion, and use input and output variables, and if theere are more than 2 keys that match, it depends on what you watn to happen, if you are expecting some to have more than 2 keys matching, then remove the final break line.

Comment: oh thanks for posting up that definition from.. that really clear some thing up !

Answer (score 1):

```
import collections
d = {'happy':['sun', 'moon', 'chocolate'], 'sad':['fail', 'test', 'bills'], 'random': ['baloon', 'france', 'sun'] }
w = collections.defaultdict(list)
for k,v in d.iteritems():
    for i in v: w[i].append(k)
print [l for l in w.itervalues() if len(l)>1]
```

gives:

```
[['random', 'happy']]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python 3 this should output a tuple of any duplicates:

```
Duplicates = [(i,j) for i in d for j in d if (d[i]==d[j]).all() and i != j]
```

Comment: my eyes are bleeding

Comment: Returns: "AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'all'" when using it on a dict. Py3.11