# Dictionary of lists - find keys in a dictionary for which the item's (lists) are the same

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I'm looking for a way to ID keys in a dictionary for which the item is identical - however, there are **hundreds** of keys, and each item is a list of upto **60-70** elements in length

I want to find all the keys which have the same item; i found this and got somewhere with it
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-find-keys-with-duplicate-values-in-dictionary/
but it's an issue when the items are lists. I converted the lists to strings and tried the flipping route, but then the keys are unwieldy (massive lists-as-strings), and seems non-pythonic.

Sample:

```
foo = {'123':['ham','salami','beef','bacon','lamb-chop'], 
       '124':['ham','salami','bacon','pepper'],
       '125':['ham','salami','bacon','pepper'],
       '126':['salami','bacon','lamb-chop']}
```

For the example above I'd be able to ID that

```
124, 125 --> ['ham','salami','bacon','pepper']
```

are the same, and

```
123 --> ['ham','salami','beef','bacon','lamb-chop']
```

and

```
126 --> ['salami','bacon','lamb-chop']
```

are separate.

The output could be a dictionary of such as:

```
'Group 1':['124,'125'],
'Group 2':['123'],
'Group 3':['126']
```

where the groupings all denote that they have the same lists elements. I don't mind too much - just would like to avoid 600+ character strings as keys to dictionaries.

I've tried building pandas dataframes from the dictionary, treating the items as sets and comparing, but i've not managed it better than the flipping route

I have a second question which is related to this so i'll put a link here when that's posted...

Comment: What does "to be able to identify" mean? Can you let us know what specific output you expect?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find Duplicate values in Dict and print keys with those values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26221692/how-to-find-duplicate-values-in-dict-and-print-keys-with-those-values)

Comment: @yatu i've edited to clarify

Answer (score -1):

You can build a reverse dict with the lists as keys (which have to be turned into immutable tuples) and the list of matching ids as values:

```
from collections import defaultdict

foo = {'123':['ham','salami','beef','bacon','lamb-chop'], 
       '124':['ham','salami','bacon','pepper'],
       '125':['ham','salami','bacon','pepper'],
       '126':['salami','bacon','lamb-chop']}

list_to_ids = defaultdict(list)

for key, lst in foo.items():
    list_to_ids[tuple(lst)].append(key)
    
print(list_to_ids)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {('ham', 'salami', 'beef', 'bacon', 'lamb-chop'): ['123'],
# ('ham', 'salami', 'bacon', 'pepper'): ['124', '125'],
# ('salami', 'bacon', 'lamb-chop'): ['126']})
```

Comment: Thanks @ThierryLathuille - that's my current approach - using the lists as the key - but the lists are enormously long and it makes further work very tricky.

Comment: You could always `hash()` the lists and work with the hashes when you don't need to know what is in the list and map the hashes back to the lists for when you need them.

Comment: Well, this is what you asked in your question... Replacing the keys by some shorter id is a completely different question, and you should clarify what you want. A hash, as suggested by @quamrana, could be a good idea if you don't need something usable by humans.

Comment: @quamrana - thanks, this appears to be the way i'm looking for (as Thierry also points out - thanks too). I'm not familiar with hash-ing, but thought it was a one-way process - how do i get the original list back?

Comment: You keep the original lists in a new `dict` keyed by the hashes,

Comment: cheers yep that's what i did, thanks again to you both